# Launch of Android app fails with sun/security/x509/X500Name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sun, ibm-mobilefirst

I can't launch my Android app (which was working fine before I upgraded the version of Worklight that I'm using) and it keeps giving the error of sun/security/x509/X500Name. Now, I've setup Android many times with Sun's Java, so I'm absolutely baffled. Here's how I've got it setup:

Project >> Properties >> Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add Library - This is where I have put my Sun Java.

Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Installed JREs - My Sun Java is ticked and is the default one.

I've even edited my eclipse.ini but with or without the following line it makes no difference: -vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\javaw.exe

I seem to remember something about I couldn't have spaces, is that true? If so, how do I replace the spaces? Even still, it should work within my Eclipse application without the need for defined my VM in this manner (or so I believe).

I'm not aware of anywhere else I need to define the Java I'm using. If I've missed anything please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to Eclipse launching as eclipse.exe in the task manager. It needs to be javaw.exe in the task manager else Android launch will FAIL.

Comment: can you please elaborate how to go about doing this .. ??? how do i run eclipse as javaw.exe

Comment: It's to do with specifying which JRE/JDK to use in your eclipse.ini file. I can't remember which way around it is, but it's either with the JRE/JDK specified in your eclipse.ini or have your ini file without it. I hope that helps you.

Comment: To get eclipse to launch as javaw.exe specify the full path to javaw.exe as the value to the -vm argument.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#-vm_specified_on_command_line_or_in_eclipse.ini.  "-vm" should be on a line by itself, and the path should be on the next line.  Spaces are ok.  Both of these should appear above the -vmargs line.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check your eclipse.ini
you need add this line
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\your_jdk_path\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

eclipse.ini

i added the route from Oracle Java(http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp):

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

and it works finally...

Answer (score 0):

I solved because I was using a 64 bits Eclipse code (installed in Program Files) and a 32 bits JDK code (installed in Program Files (x86)). It stopped happening since I installed the 64 bits JDK kit.